# Unable to send email using PHP SMTP, Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I have been trying for last 3 days to resolve the issue and have searched many websites and stackoverflow question but it seems my code is perfect but still it is not working.

```
function send_email(){
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.shadowmail.com.au";
    $config['smtp_port'] = 587;

    $config['smtp_timeout']='30';

    $config['smtp_user'] = "my email id here "; //
    $config['smtp_pass'] = "******";

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
    $this->email->from("my email id here ", "Test");

    $this->email->to("jack@gmail.com");

    $this->email->subject("heading");
    $this->email->message("heyyyyyyyyyyyy");
    if($this->email->send()){
        echo "done";
    }else{echo "fail";
        show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
}
```

This error I am getting

```
220 Sol1-SMEX01.shadowmail.sol1 Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Thu, 18 Jan 2018 10:39:18 +1100 

hello: 250-Sol1-SMEX01.shadowmail.sol1 Hello [1.136.213.103]
250-SIZE 41943040
250-PIPELINING
250-DSN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-AUTH GSSAPI NTLM
250-8BITMIME
250-BINARYMIME
250 CHUNKING
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error: 504 5.7.4 Unrecognized authentication type 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
Date: Thu, 18 Jan 2018 00:39:28 +0100
From: "Test" <my email id was here , i just replaced it with this text>
Return-Path: <my email id was here , i just replaced it with this text>
To: jack@gmail.com
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?heading?=
Reply-To: <my email id was here , i just replaced it with this text>
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
X-Sender: my email id was here , i just replaced it with this text
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5a5fdeb00e005@example.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

heyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

It could be basic question for you but I have been trying for last 3 days and still getting same error. It seems code is ok, might be something is wrong I am unable to identify. 
My email id and password are correct, I have logged in many times to verify that credentials are working.

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter's email library doesn't seem to support anything but the most basic, insecure authentication method, [`LOGIN`, basically plaintext] and your SMTP server only supports actual secure authentication methods. [`GSSAPI` and `NTLM`]

You need either need to:

1. Use TLS/SSL.

   - Secure channels usually allow insecure auth, aka `LOGIN`
   - Unfortunately your host doesn't seems to have it configured, as there's no `STARTTLS` in the listed capabilities.
2. Use an email library actually supports one of these methods.

Of these options #1 is your best bet because:

1. You should neither use nor pay money for an email host that doesn't use SSL in this day and age.
2. I can't find any PHP email lib advertising support for either `GSSAPI` or `NTLM`.

**TLDR:** You're going to have to yell at your host.

Comment: My Email host company says they are using following encryption Encryption: SSL\TLS , but when I add  ssl://mail.shadowmail.com.au    I get "Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol"   error from my Email library  on   Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 2055

Comment: does it mean something wrong with my ssl certificate

Comment: I got this response form server when trying to send email                                                                   
  The following SMTP error was encountered: 0 
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

Comment: You should double check with them about exactly *how* they have it implemented, because neither `STARTTLS` nor a pure TLS negotiation works for the server you've specified.

Comment: I am trying with gmail and getting same problem ,                                    $config = Array(
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => '******@gmail.com',
            'smtp_pass' => '******',
            'mailtype'  => 'html',
            'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
        );

        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

Comment: Getting this error 
Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still trying to figure this one out but

Port 587 is used for a TLS connection. 465 is for the SSL connection.

There is an additional variable you need to set in the email config library.

You also remove "ssl://" from the hostname.

So you would config like this for TLS connection:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "mail.shadowmail.com.au";
$config['smtp_port'] = 587;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = "tls";
```

Or this for an SSL connection:

```
$config['smtp_host'] = "mail.shadowmail.com.au";
$config['smtp_port'] = 465;
$config['smtp_crypto'] = "ssl";
```

That being said I seem to be finding some issues with the TLS connection the past couple weeks suddenly not working. Something may have changed somewhere to cause this.